# Response Modification in HTTP Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I built an http module in C# that just overrides the EndRequest of a lifecycle, checks the status code of the response header and modifies the response code it if needs be.  Something like:

```
HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)source).Context;
if (context.Response.StatusCode == 200)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

This seems to work fine for me when I test it against localhost (real IIS), but when I enable intranet access and test from another computer it fails every time.

The error I am seeing when I test via another computer is:

"Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent."

I also noticed that requests the same file twice, whereas locally it only requests the file once.  I heard someone say something about output buffering, but I also tried setting the on BeginRequest response OutputBuffer to true and got the same results.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the response before the headers are sent.  I've never had to do this, but I would guess the correct event would be `PreSendRequestHeaders`. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[Here's an example](http://www.google.com/codesearch#kZG2CHKIKf8/trunk/1.0a/OAuth.Net.ServiceProvider/Authentication/OAuthPipelineModule.cs&q=PreSendRequestHeaders%20lang%3a%5Ec#%24&type=cs) of setting headers in this event.

If this event doesn't work for you, check out some events after the handler's post process in the pipeline: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2007/12/19/application-page-and-control-lifecycle.aspx  Be careful, though, because you may have to rewrite your code for the IIS 7 integrated pipeline.

Comment: Just thought I would come back around and close this out.  There were two problems here, the first of which your suggestion solved.  The second problem was related to pipeline, but not asp.net's.  IIS has a "feature" for returning particular error pages when certain status codes are sent out.  This happens AFTER the processing takes place in .NET, but you can sort of turn it off.  If you enable "detailed errors" and remove handler for status code, you will get the original page content returned unmodified.  By default, this is local only.